# Sort a field with in a 2D Array

Tags: c#, sorting

```
class Baby
{
     string Name;
     Birth Birthy;
}

class Birth
{
     String BirthCity
     string HospitalName;
     DateTime Birthday;
}
```

I need to sort Birth collection of object array by **DateTime Birthday**

im thinking something like

```
Foreach(Baby...)
{
     Foreach(Birth....)
     {
         ...Sort(....)
     }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `Birth collection of object array` - what do you mean? What does this collection look like? How does it relate to Baby and what language are you using?

Comment: C#, pretty much an collect of an object contains another collection of object and in this 2nd collection there is a property Date, i just need to sort the 2nd collection by Date

Comment: do you nead each collection stored in the first collection sorted by Date?

Comment: no only the second collection

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a job for linq

```
List<Birth> sorted = source.OrderBy(b => b.Birthday).ToList()
```

or if you need to sort the babies

```
List<Baby> sorted = source.OrderBy(b => b.Birthy.Birthday).ToList()
```